# JQuery select form input value from dynamically loaded array of rows

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have a form that I can load multiple input rows of a form when clicking a button.  Each input has a name so I can make an array.

For example, my input looks like

```
<select name='Area[]' onchange='getSame($(this).val(),$("select[name=Rack]").val())' id='MdWd'>
        <options>(options pulled in through php)</select>
<select name='Rack[]' onchange='getSame($("select[name=Area[]]").val(),$(this).val())' id='MdWd'>
        <options>(options pulled in through php)</select>
```

I can end up loading multiple rows of these selector options.  I can get the value of the current one using the $(this).val selector on any of the dynamically loaded rows.

But I can't figure out how to get the value of the sister selector (I have 4 all together) from the SAME row to pass to my function.

I've tried select[name=Rack], select[name=Rack[]] like shown.  I've tried just [name=Rack] (without input).  And I've tried a bunch of things, but I cant figure it out.

Because I allow dynamically loaded rows, I can have between 1 and 15 rows.  How can I get the value from ALL 4 of my select boxes each time I change the selection on just one of them?  But get the value from that row?

I hope I explained that well enough.

EDIT:

I found that if I use

```
$('select[name^=Rack]').val()
```

I at least get the value of the first row.  But if I add a 2nd or 3rd or more rows, I still only get the value from the first rows select options.  But at least its getting values now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a script to add these input fields.

.html

```
<button id="clickme">Append input field</button>
<div id="foo">
  <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Your name">
</div>
```

.js (using jQuery)

```
var field_name = 0;
$('body').on('click','#clickme', function(event) {
  field_name++;
  $('#foo').append('<input type="text" name="name'+field_name+'" placeholder="Your name">');
})
```

Edit: Inputs are named "name1", "name2",...,"nameN". This way it's easy for you to retrieve its values.

Since you're using select, do the same procedure as above:

.html

```
<button id="clickme">Append options</button>
<select id="foo">
</select>
```

.js

```
var option = 0;
$('body').on('click','#clickme', function(event) {
  option++;
  ('#foo').append('<option name="'+option+'">Option name</option>')
})
```

To retrieve the values you can use on your .js

```
$("body").on('change','#foo', function() {
  // Code to retrieve values here
});
```

Comment: I'll have to look at this more.  But I'm not exactly sure how I implement this, since my <option> values are all loaded dynamically through php/mysql items.  And also submitting the form becomes more complicated because I loop through the variable array after submitting.  But I'll try it out and see what I can do in case there really is no other way to just read the current values using jquery.